# Epsilon-delta proof of a multivariate limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

I'd like to find $$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(-2,1,-1)} f(x,y,z)$$ where $$f(x,y,z) = \frac{\sin(x+4y+2z)}{(x+4y+2z)}$$ I know that the limit should be 1, and I have a feeling that I should attempt to find the limit by using the fact that $$\lim_{u\to0} \frac{\sin(u)}{u} = 1$$ but I don't know how to use this fact in the case of multivariable limits. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Take $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\sin u}u=1$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $0<|u|<\delta\implies\left|\frac{\sin u}u\right|<\varepsilon$. Now, if $\|(x,y,z)-(-2,1,-1)\|<\frac{\delta}7$, then$$|x+2|,|y-1|,|z+1|<\frac{\delta}7.$$So\begin{align}|x+4y+2z|&=\bigl|(x+2)+4(y-1)+2(z+1)\bigr|\\&\leqslant|x+2|+4|y-1|+2|z+1|\\&<\frac{\delta}7+4\frac{\delta}7+2\frac{\delta}7\\&=\delta,\end{align}and therefore, by the choice of $\delta$,$$\left|\frac{\sin(x+4y+2z)}{x+4y+2z}\right|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: There is no need to compute the norm (since it could be any norm...) $||(x,y,z)-(-2,1,-1)||$... cf. my answer.

Comment: @Netchaiev In the context of multivariable calculus, then the norm that it is being used is the usual one, unless it is explicitly stated otherwise. Anyway, since all norms are equivalent this is a moot point.

Comment: Is the conclusion that I can draw from this that I can choose $\delta = 7\epsilon$?

Comment: @Taliant No. You take a $\delta$ that works for the given $\varepsilon$ and for the function $\frac{\sin x}x$ and then you divide it by $7$.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 :
You can use the fact (a bit more accurate) that 
$$ \sin(u)=u+ o(u)$$
(which is true for all $u\in \mathbb{R}$, but which have an interest only near $0$)
so, you will have 
$$\frac{\sin(x+4y+2z)}{x+4y+2z}= \frac{x+4y+2z+o(x+4y+2z)}{x+4y+2z}= 1 + o(1)\rightarrow 0$$
(when $(x,y,z)\rightarrow (-2,1,-1)$).

Method 2 :

Let $\varepsilon >0 $.

Since $\lim \frac{\sin(u)}{u}=1$, 
$$\exists \delta_1>0, \quad |u|\leq \delta_1 \Rightarrow \Big|\frac{\sin(u)}{u}-1\Big| <\varepsilon $$

Since $f: (x,y,z)\mapsto x+4x+2z$ is continuous and $f(-2,1,-1)=0$, 
$$\exists \delta_2>0, \quad || (x,y,z)-(-2,1,-1)||\leq \delta_2 \Rightarrow |f(x,y,z)-f(-2,1,-1)|=|f(x,y,z)| <\delta_1 $$

So, there exists $\delta_2>0$ for every $(x,y,z)$ such that $|| (x,y,z)-(-2,1,-1)||\leq \delta_2$, ($\Rightarrow$ $|f(x,y,z)| <\delta_1$ $\Rightarrow$)
$$ \Big|  \frac{\sin(x+4y+2z)}{x+4y+2z}-1  \Big| =\Big|  \frac{\sin(f(x,y,z) )}{f(x,y,z)}-1  \Big|< \varepsilon .$$

Comment: How could I formulate that into an epsilon-delta argument?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to answer to that.